# JavaScript ignore alert if reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am detecting the end of a webrtc stream in JavaScript like this...

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = () => {
    alert('Feed Has Ended');
};
```

This is working correctly, but if the user refreshes or reloads the page then the alert is also shown.

I understand that this is technically correct, but how can I get it to not display the alert under those conditions?

Comment: So, you want the alert to be shown only on the *first* time the user visits the page and when the video stream ends?

Comment: you can pick up what key they hit -> can't remember what values link up to what key, but you could use that in your conditional. The only thing that this doesn't take care of, is if the user uses the mouse to refresh

Comment: You have to store some boolean flag in localStorage or cookies.

Comment: @treyBake don't think you can catch F5 / Control-F5 / back with alt-left/backspace / history.go(-1) / right-click back / right-click reload / right-clicking back-button and selecting from the menu / etc

Comment: @freedomn-m you can't do F1-F12 as I've just found out .. maybe not as robust as I thought :S

Comment: Do you get a `.onplay` event when the page refreshes?  If not, store that it was started and check that onended.

Comment: To be clear, you want the alert to be shown when the feed ends naturally, and not when it ends due to a user interaction such as reloading the page, going back, going forward, or any other user action.

Comment: Just use a cookie

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a global boolean to check if video is playing or not? When you will reload or refresh the page, isVideoRunning will become false and alert won't show.

Like

```
this.isVideoRunning = false;
```

On addtrack,

```
this.rtcPeerCon_.ontrack = function (event) {
    if (!this.rtcPeerCon_) {
        return;
    }
    if( !this.remoteVideo_ ) {
        return;
    }
    this.remoteVideo_.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    this.isVideoRunning = true;
}
```

then in your onStream ended callback you can check

```
if (this.isVideoRunning) {
    alert('whatever');
    this.isVideoRunning = false;
}
```

(I wanted this to be comment but I am not allowed to comment yet)